# MS SSIS: Import Data from REST API into SQL Table. ERROR (401) "Unauthorized" by Using ZappySys

Tags: sql-server, ssis, http-status-code-401, rest, unauthorized

I need to Import Json Data from REST Api (BMC Discovery) into SQL Server Table.

A local connection with a token and execution from Visual Studio works perfectly.
But once deployed on the SQL server, my package returns the error 401 "Unauthorized".
It looks like the credentials of the REST API user or token are not being passed on and SQL Server failed to authenticate the request.

Given is SQL Server Version/Build: 13.0.4604.0.
SQL Server executionaccount is a default technical local account.

Help me please to resolve this

Many thanks in advance

Irina

Comment: How are you running the package on the server?  What kind of authentication does the REST API use?

Comment: I have deployed es at the SSIS Instance. Then I execute es manually by right click on the Package.  "What kind of authentication?" - token. Du you mean I should try to execute the package by scheduled Job? Thank you